# New environment for Python source code

Tags: listings, minted

I am trying hard to create an environment for my source code. Here's my current state

```
\documentclass[a4paper,fontsize=12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{beton,euler}
\usepackage[english]{babel}


\usepackage{minted}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.95,0.95,0.95}
\newminted{python3}{bgcolor=bg, tabsize=4}

\newenvironment{sourcecode}[1]
{
    \def\savedcaption{\caption{#1}}
    \begin{listing}[ht]
    \begin{python3code}
}
{
    \end{python3code}
    \savedcaption
    \end{listing}
}

\title{Research}

\author{Me}

\date{\today}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{sourcecode}{"Hello"}
print("Hello")
\end{sourcecode}

\end{document}
```

I get fancyVerbErrors. I am lost. Any help would be very appreciated

Comment: Please post a _complete_  example that we can run to get the errors, a fragment is not so useful,

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do what you want.

```
\newenvironment{sourcecode}[1]
{%
    \VerbatimEnvironment
    \def\savedcaption{\caption{#1}}%
    \begin{listing}[ht]%
    \begin{python3code}%
}
{%
    \end{python3code}%
    \savedcaption
    \end{listing}%
}
```

You need `\VerbatimEnvironment`, because you are creating an environment that uses `fancyvrb` internally.  You need a `%` after `\begin{python3code}` to prevent the newline that follows it from being treated as a space and triggering a `fancyvrb` error.

Comment: @tschm I just added a note on this to the documentation for the next version of `minted`, so it should be easier to find in the future.