# Memoir - New environment using new float for including source code highlighter minted

Tags: floats, environments, memoir, minted

I am using memoir for typesetting some python source code examples. I was able to declare ftlisting float for memoir as per minted's creator's github suggestion.  List of these floats was successfully printed at the beginning of the document.

```
\begin{pyprog}{Title of Program}{prog-label}
import os, numpy
a = 25 
print(a)
print("Hello World")
\end{pyprog}
```

I am stuck up at creating a new environment pyprog, as shown above, which takes two arguments Title and Label and wraps minted in ftlisting float environment, please help me.

```
% !TeX document-id = {e0f3a9c2-ac76-43b6-9d06-b802f7bc550a}
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///pdflatex/[--shell-escape]
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newlistof{listofprograms}{lol}{List of Programs}
\newfloat[chapter]{ftlisting}{lol}{Program}
\newlistentry{ftlisting}{lol}{0}

\usepackage[all]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{hyperref}
% Hyperref settings
\hypersetup{
    unicode=true,
    bookmarks=true,
    bookmarksopen=true,
    pdfstartview=FitH,
    pdfpagelayout=OneColumn,
    pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
    colorlinks=true,
    linkcolor=colLink,
    urlcolor=colLink,
    citecolor=colLink,
    bookmarksnumbered
}

\usepackage[nameinlink]{cleveref}

\crefname{ftlisting}{Program}{Programs}


\newenvironment{pyprog}[pyprog=fr,2]{
    \begin{ftlisting}[H]
        \def\tempcaption{#1}
        \def\templabel{#2}
        \begin{minted}
        }{
        \end{minted}
        \caption{\tempcaption}
        \label{\templabel}
    \end{ftlisting}
}



\begin{document}
    
    
    
    \listofprograms

\section{This is working}   
    
    
The float environment is working fine for  \Cref{prog-intro} with minted listing and is printed in the listofprograms also.


\begin{ftlisting}[H]

\begin{minted}[
frame=lines,
framesep=2mm,
baselinestretch=1.2,
fontsize=\footnotesize
]{python}

import os, numpy as np

#initialise a with 25
a=25

print("Hello World from ftlisting float")
\end{minted}
\caption{Listing First one }
\label{prog-intro}
\end{ftlisting}


\section{Environment defined for pyprog is not working}

\begin{pyprog}{hello world}{prog-env}

import os, django.contrib

# This code is included using pyprog environment

print("Hello World from pyprog environment)
    
\end{pyprog}



    
\end{document}
```

line 84: Missing \endcsname inserted.
line 84: Extra \endcsname.
line 85: FancyVerb Error:. import os, django.contrib
line 91: Missing \endcsname inserted. \end{pyprog}
line 91: Package minted Error: Missing Pygments output; \inputminted wasor may be using frozencache with a missing file. \end{pyprog}
line 26: Option `bookmarks' has already been used,(hyperref) setting the option has no effect

The following answers I referred for the above code.

1. https://github.com/gpoore/minted/issues/67
2. [New environment for Python source code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289470/new-environment-for-python-source-code)

Comment: Does it work without hyperref? (not at pc, so cannot test)

Comment: Without hyperref also it is not working. Error is Missing \endcsname inserted.

Comment: I do not understand your `\newenvironment[pyprog=fr, 2]{...`  in your MWE. In your introductory text you say you call it like `\begin{pyprog}{Title of Program}{prog lab}` which has no relationship as to how you defined the environment. Please read and understand the code for defining a new environment.